# openpyxl to read from Excel file

Tags: python, excel, loops, pycharm, openpyxl

I have some code which I want to use to iterate through some rows in excel, and for this i openpyxl.

I would like to, for each row, print something like this:

```
'The product id is: ' + column 1 + 'and the product is: ' + column 2
```

But I don't know how to distinguish between the columns in the code.
The code I have right now is the following:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file = load_workbook('path...file.xlsx')
list = file.active

for value in list.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_col=2, values_only=True):
    print(value)
```

And the result I get is the following:

```
('ProductID', 'Product')
('xxx', 'xxx')
...
('yyy', 'yyy')
```

So I can use the entire row, but I'm unsure as to how I should refer to each individual cell in the row when I print.

Is there a different way I should do this?

Comment: `print(value[0])` and `print(value[1])`?

Comment: Thank you! This works, didn't know I could do this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do open file and use `readlines()` then iterate through the lines and use the comma separate the values in to list and use for e.g. `value[0]` as `id` and `value[1]` as `product`.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file = load_workbook('path...file.xlsx')
sheet = file.active

for row in range(sheet.max_row):
    cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=1)
    print(cell.value)
```